# Understanding Big O | n^2 ∈ O(n^3)?

Tags: computer-science, discrete-mathematics

How do we prove that n^2 ∈ O(n^3)?

I know how to prove questions like 3n^2 + 4 ∈ O(n^2) but none like the one above. Is there a similar process?

Answer (score 0):

But even at a glance, it's not true.  n^2 ∈ O(n^2).  So I hope you CANNOT prove n^2 ∈ O(n^3).

Big O means that the complexity is proportional (times a constant) to the given expression as n grows without bound.  And n^2 is not proportional to n^3 for large n.  The important part of a **disproof** would go like this.

Suppose it was proportional: then there would be some equivalent T(n) = c · n^2.  But n^3 = n · n^2, and we can always chose n > c, so it's not true.